# how to convert the string number between comma in python list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Here is the given list which i want to convert into int list without removing comma

```
['3,2', '3,2', '3', '3,3']
```

My Desired output is

```
[3,2, 3,2, 3, 3,3]
```

Any Help would be appreciated thanks in Advance

Comment: `print([int(j) for i in lst for j in i.split(",")])` ?

Comment: thanks @Rakesh for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `join` and `split`

```
lst = ['3,2', '3,2', '3', '3,3']

res = list(map(int, ','.join(lst).split(',')))
print(res)

# output [3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```